# Python Multiprocessing With (LIFO) Queues

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, lifo

I'm trying to use multiprocessing in Python to have a function keep getting called within a loop, and subsequently access the latest return value from the function (by storing the values in a LIFO Queue).

Here is a code snippet from the main program

```
q = Queue.LifoQueue()
while True:
   p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myFunc, args = (q))
   p.daemon = True
   p.start()
   if not q.empty():
      #do something with q.get()
```

And here's a code snippet from myFunc

```
def myFunc(q):
    x = calc()
    q.put(x)
```

The problem is, the main loop thinks that q is empty. However, I've checked to see if myFunc() is placing values into q (by putting a q.empty() check right after the q.put(x)) and the queue shouldn't be empty.

What can I do so that the main loop can see the values placed in the queue? Or am I going about this in an inefficient way? (I do need myFunc and the main loop to be run separately though, since myFunc is a bit slow and the main loop needs to keep performing its task)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691392/how-to-implement-lifo-for-multiprocessing-queue-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Queue.LifoQueue` is not fit for multiprocessing, only `multiprocessing.Queue` is, at is it specially designed for this usecase. That means that values put into a `Queue.LifoQueue` will only be available to the local process, as the queue is not shared between subprocesses.

A possibility would be to use a shared list from a SyncManager ([`SyncManager.list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list)) instead. When used with only `append` and `pop`, a list behaves just like a lifo queue.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out SyncManager.list() and see if it works. Do you think for what I'm trying to do though, multiprocessing is the best way to go?